# About Hierarchical Latent Dirichlet allocation (hLDA)

Tags: topic-models, nonparametric-bayes, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I am reading Blei et al.'s paper (Hierarchical Topic Models and
the Nested Chinese Restaurant Process) about hLDA.

I am confused about the details of deriving the posterior of $p(\boldsymbol c_m| \boldsymbol w, \boldsymbol c_{-\boldsymbol m}, \boldsymbol z)$. What is the exact formula of this posterior? How could I draw $\boldsymbol c_m$ from this posterior?

Sincerely thanks for giving helps.

Comment: Possibly this would help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265038/question-about-implementing-nested-chinese-restaurant-process-ncrp?rq=1.